# Ошибка : Команда не поддерживается объектом

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Во всех браузерах нормально отображается, кроме ie11. Пытаюсь сделать:

```
var tmpUrl = new URL(url);
```

И выдает ошибку:

> Команда не поддерживается объектом

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=url IE не поддерживает URL API

Comment: Странный вопрос. Потому что сайтоделатели не объединились и не стали игнорировать IE. Или выдавать сразу на сайте: "У Вас не правильный браузер, идите мимо!". В крайнем случае: "Установите Хром и будет Вам счастье" и ссылку.

Comment: @Leonid если слать всех кто на IE, то это приведет к потере примерно 10% потенциальных клиентов

Comment: Не согласен, это приведёт к тому, что 90% из этих 10% пересядут, наконец, на норм браузеры. Особенно, если не смогут открыть YouTube, Google, Facebook и т.д.

Comment: @Leonid, поверьте, не пересядут. Раз они сидят на IE, значит они и не знают как можно установить что-то другое. И это наверняка люди в возрасте

Comment: Ага, надо вроде цифрового телевидения, бесплатный специалист на дом для установки хрома)

Comment: @Leonid, хром не панацея

Comment: Извиняюсь, Firefox, конечно))))) Но по сравнению с IE даже Edge  панацея.

Comment: Может полифил поможет? [url-polyfill](https://github.com/lifaon74/url-polyfill)

Answer (score 0):

IE не поддерживает URL API - [caniuse.com/#feat=url](https://caniuse.com/#feat=url)